# Google Analytics event tracking does not work

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, web, tracking

I am developing a website, and it has been published on the 23rd of April.
The general tracking code was inserted on the day we published the website. 
Overview data, DAU, page views and so on are available from yesterday.

All I need to do is only inserting Google Analytics Event Tracking Code.

However, I put the all of the event tracking code yesterday but it does not seem to work.

The page - Real-time > event or behaviour > events have no result. 
Even if it takes more than 48 hours for GA to show date, the real-time view is supposed to show the outcome. But they have no date

What would be a problem? 
They are the code below.

---

```
<!-- header -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="/html/Layout.html" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Nav', 'Menus', 'BI');">Live tax</a></h1>
        <div class="gnb">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="go01" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Nav', 'Menus', 'Introduction');">Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="go02" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Nav', 'Menus', 'Features');">Major Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="go03" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Nav', 'Menus', 'Inquiry');">Inquiry</a></li>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is not working exactly?  Please include your full snippet.   How long ago did you create the account a new google analytics account can take up to 48 - 72 hours to start recording data it can take up to 24 - 48 hours for new data to show up in standard reports.   Have you checked the real-time reports?

Comment: I put more details about the problem. I already checked the event view of real-time reports on GA. But there is no date.

Comment: Is it recording any data at all right now?  or is just the events missing?  Please include your full Javascript snippet not just the event tracking.

Comment: Install a debugger such as this one (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) and see what the console says.

Comment: The test website is [here](http://www.livetax.net/html/Layout.html).                                                                
            Only event tracking is a problem. other date and reports have no issues.

Comment: Please add your `ga('create', ...)` code to your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your website (http://www.livetax.net/html/Layout.html) you've created your tracking object as a [named tracker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#naming_trackers). This is for when you want multiple trackers on a page. When your events attempt to fire, they are not specifying a tracker and you are getting this in GA debug:

```
Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

This is your create code. Note the 'name' field:

```
ga("create", "...", {cookieDomain: "auto", name: "..."})
```

You should either remove the name or refer to the name when you fire your events. You can see (with GA debug switch on) that your pageviews are specifying the tracker:

```
ga("<name>.send", "pageview", {forceSSL: true, &gtm: "u46", hitCallback: [function]})
```

If you decide to remove the name from your create call, I *think* you'll need to remove it from here as well.

Alternatively you can specify the tracker name in your events. Currently you're triggering your events like this:

```
ga("send", "event", "네비게이션", "메뉴 이동", "서비스 소개")
```

You can just add the name and a `.` before `send` so it's something like `name.send`. The event should then get sent correctly.

For the future, I recommend installing the GA debugger [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) so that you can debug future problems quickly.

Comment: Thanks! The event tracking works well since I put the create code!. @Rajit You are so helpful and great! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad I could help! If you're happy with my answer, please do "accept" it. Thanks!

Comment: I did it! I was unaware of "accept" process. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!